What is the difference between 拌嘴 and 吵嘴 and 口角 and 争吵 ? Feel free to just provide example sentences
The Chinese words ‘吵架, 吵嘴, 拌嘴, 口角’ all mean quarrel. But how do I use these words in practice? The explanation in the dictionary is not clear. Personally, I think the word ‘quarrel’ should be the most commonly used. The Chinese word ‘’拌嘴‘’ should require the understanding of the word ‘’拌‘’ but I can't understand it. Is the Chinese word ‘口角’ a noun or a verb? I feel that this word is very formal.
I wonder if my analysis is correct.

"吵架," "吵嘴," "拌嘴," and "口角" can all refer to verbal arguments, but there are differences:

口角 (kǒu jué): formal word for verbal dispute/altercation. Example:


他们在会议上发生了口角。
They had a verbal altercation during the meeting.

"口角" can mean either "嘴边" (noun, pronounced kǒu jiǎo), or "争吵" (verb, pronounced kǒu jué).

吵架 (chǎo jià): most common term for a quarrel, typically used for more serious or heated arguments. Example:


通常人们是因为不会辩理才吵架的。
People usually argue because they don't know how to reason properly.


吵嘴 (chǎo zuǐ): to bicker or argue in a less intense, more trivial form of argument. Example:


她总是跟他吵嘴。
She's always bickering with him.


拌嘴 (bàn zuǐ): a tiff, arguments in a more lighthearted or teasing way. Example:


你俩拌嘴的样子就跟对老夫老妻似的。
You guys are tiffing like an old married couple.

"拌嘴" is a compound word, where "拌" itself means to argue or quarrel. For example:

也没见你们两个人有些什么可拌的，三日好了，两日恼了，越大越成了孩子了！
I don't see why you two should always be wrangling! For three days you're on good terms and for two on bad. You become more and more like children.
—— 《红楼梦》第三十回　宝钗借扇机带双敲　龄官划蔷痴及局外 (translated by H. Bencraft Joly)


Well explained. My (perhaps overly simplified) rules: use 口角 for news, use 拌嘴 for trivial tiffs between close friends and family, use 吵架 in most cases, and don’t use 吵嘴 (just treat it as a less common version of 拌嘴).

Thank you 湛雪_! Very much appreciated!!!

It is correct that ‘吵架, 吵嘴, 拌嘴, 口角’ all mean quarrel, other than regional differences in which to use, I think the seriousness of the quarreler treating the matter in dispute, and the degree of hostility between the two, also matters.
IMO, "吵架" is the most serious form of quarreling. The hostility can linger long after it ends, turning the parties into enemies or escalating to a physical fight. "吵架" can occur between two strangers.
"吵嘴, 拌嘴, 口角" usually starts with disputes over minor matters between two acquaintances, or a couple. The hostility, if any, usually is short-lived, though it can escalate to "吵架" too.
